# GAE + NDB + Blobstore + Google High Performance Image Serving

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, blobstore, app-engine-ndb

I'm making an app to upload text and images. I've readed a lot about blobstore and Google High Performance Image Serving and finally I got a way to implement it all together.

What I want to know is if all is well done or can be do in a better way, and also if it is better to save the serving_url in the model or must be calculated every time I want to print the images in the page.

There is a User and a Picture only.

This is the code (summarized, forget about my custom.PageHandler, that only have functions to render the pages easily, and the stuff for check forms values, etc.):

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    """ A User """
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

class Picture(ndb.Model):
    """ All pictures that a User has uploaded """
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    blobKey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(required=True)
    servingUrl = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)

# This class shows the user pics
class List(custom.PageHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Get the actual user pics
        pics = Picture.by_user(self.user.key)
        for pic in pics:
            pic.servingUrl = images.get_serving_url(pic.blobKey, size=90, crop=True)
        self.render_page("myPictures.htm", data=pics)

# Get and post for the send page
class Send(custom.PageHandler, blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def get(self):
        uploadUrl = blobstore.create_upload_url('/addPic')
        self.render_page("addPicture.htm", form_action=uploadUrl)

    def post(self):
        # Create a dictionary with the values, we will need in case of error
        templateValues = self.template_from_request()
        # Test if all data form is valid
        testErrors = check_fields(self)

        if testErrors[0]:
            # No errors, save the object
            try:
                # Get the file and upload it
                uploadFiles = self.get_uploads('picture')
                # Get the key returned from blobstore, for the first element
                blobInfo = uploadFiles[0]
                # Add the key to the template
                templateValues['blobKey'] = blobInfo.key()

                # Save all
                pic = Picture.save(self.user.key, **templateValues)
                if pic is None:
                    logging.error('Picture save error.')

                self.redirect("/myPics")

            except:
                self.render_page("customMessage.htm", custom_msg=_("Problems while uploading the picture."))
        else:
            # Errors, render the page again, with the values, and showing the errors
            templateValues = custom.prepare_errors(templateValues, testErrors[1])
            # The session for upload a file must be new every reload page
            templateValues['form_action'] = blobstore.create_upload_url('/addPic')

            self.render_page("addPicture.htm", **templateValues)
```

Basically, I list all the pics, showing the image in a jinja2 template with this line:

```
{% for line in data %}
  <tr>
    <td class="col-center-data"><img src="{{ line.servingUrl }}"></td>
```

So in the List class I calculate each serving url and add it temporarily to the Model. I don't know exactly if will be good to save it directly in the Model, because I don't know if the url can change with the time. Will be the url permanent for the image? In that case I can save it instead of calculate, true?

The Send class only shows a form to upload the image and saves the data to the Model. I always generate a new form_action link in the case of re-render the page, because docs talk about it. Is it right?

The code is working, but I want to know which is the better way to do it, in terms of performance and resource-saving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right.  You do want to save the get_serving_url() instead of calling it repeatedly.  It stays the same.

Note that there's a delete_serving_url() when you're done with the url, like when you delete the blob.